# KeyError on dictionary access but still returning correct value?

Tags: python, http, response, keyerror

So Python is behaving quite weirdly at the moment. I wrote a very simple server that is intended to return the value of the HTTP GET parameter "url". Behavior wise, this works as intended; the server retrieves the parameter with the key 'url' and returns its value. However, on output, the Python interpreter is throwing a KeyError, saying that the key 'url' does not exist.

```
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/workspace/backend/ServerHandler.py", line 12, in getURL
  return dictionary['url']
  KeyError: 'url'
```

The code looks as follow:

```
def dictify(self, full_path):
    return urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(full_path).query)

def getURL(self, full_path):
    dictionary = self.dictify(full_path)
    return dictionary['url']

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(self.getURL(self.path))
```

Here is the request: http://localhost:5000/?val=4&url=Hello+World

However, as intended, the result is correct.

[image]

While this is pleasing to have the result correct, I'm still confused as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Why won't you `print dictionary` before the return statement and see what's in there ?

Comment: @alfasin Just figured it out. Part of the Google Chrome bug where it sends two HTTP requests to the same server on page load because of the favicon thing...